# Add XML option to Export option on Django Admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-serializer, django-import-export

So am using Django Admin to export various models in different formats using the Django-import-export package. The only option that is missing is XML. Is there a way to add an XML option? Any guidance would be appreciated!

Attached you will find a screenshot :

[image]

According to this [post](https://github.com/praekelt/django-export) XML is possible.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR - No not today.

Couple of things...

1. You linked to django-export. This tag is about django-import-export. They're different plugins.
2. django-import-export uses Tablib for the export and it does not currently support XML.
   See https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/issues/104 and https://github.com/kennethreitz/tablib

Hope that helps